# In Wildfly, what is the /subsystem?

Tags: wildfly

I have been reviewing documentation for Wildfly with the intention of adding LDAP security for a Drools Workbench application, more on that much later, and a notation that I see in many places is something like ...

`/subsystem=elytron/security-domain=jdbcdomain:add(default-realm=jdbcRealm,realms=[{realm="jdbcRealm"}])`

What is this?

Is this a command to be entered at the command line in Linux or Windows?

Maybe an entry in a config file?

Perhaps something entered after starting the jboss-cli?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Also, take a look at the file `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` in the Wildfly installation directory to get an idea of what these command ultimately update.  You don't have to understand all of it but you'll see the different subsystems.

Answer (score 3):

That's a WildFly configuration operation on jboss-cli.